# Python: Erro ao traduzir texto com o api translate

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou tentando fazer uma tradução com o api GoogleTrans(https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/).
Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

print translator.translate('hello', dest='pt')
```

Recebo o erro:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 35:
 ordinal not in range(128)
```

Pode me ajudar nesta questão?
Estou usando **PYTHON 2.7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve especificar que espera uma string unicode:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

print unicode(translator.translate('hello', dest='pt'))
# Translated(src=en, dest=pt, text=Olá, pronunciation=None)

# O unicode não é necessário para mostrar só o texto
print translator.translate('hello', dest='pt').text
# Olá
```

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 114-115:
 character maps to <undefined> 
E se isto ocorrer?